# Let $|G|=n,m\in\Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Let $\sigma:G\to G$ be $\sigma(g)=g^{m}\forall g\in G$. If $G$ is abelian, then $\sigma\in{\rm Aut}(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Here is the problem.

> Let $|G|=n,$ and let $m$ be an integer with $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n)=1 .$ Define $\sigma: G \rightarrow G$ by $\sigma(g)=g^{m}$ for all $g \in G .$ If $G$ is abelian, show that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $G$.

I proved that $\sigma$ is bijection. For the rest, I tried as follows:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group with $|G|=n$. Let $m$ be an integer with $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n)=1 .$ Define $\sigma: G \rightarrow G$ by $\sigma(g)=g^{m}$ for all $g \in G .$ We prove that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $G$. By Corollary of Lagrange's Theorem, we observe that $g^{n}=1$ for all $g \in G$.
>
> Now we show that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism. Let $g, h \in G$. If $m \geq 0$, we have
>   $$
> \sigma(gh)=(gh)^{m} =g^{m} h^{m}= \sigma(g)\sigma(h).
> $$
>   If $m<0$, there is $c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m=-c$. Then we see that
>   $$\begin{align}
> \sigma(gh)&=(gh)^{m} \\
> &=(gh)^{-c}\\
> & = ((gh)^{-1})^{c}\\
> &=(h^{-1}g^{-1})^c\\
> &=h^{-c}g^{-c}\\
> &=h^{m}g^{m}\\
> &=g^{m}h^{m}\\
> &= \sigma(g)\sigma(h).
> \end{align}$$
>   Hereby, $\sigma$ is an isomorphism.

Here is my question:

1) Is the proof right?

2) Did I use correctly the condition that $G$ is abelain?

Thanks!!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem: I was thinking $G$ was cyclic.  So I take it you used Lagrange to prove bijectivity.  But I was wondering why you brought it up again.  Anyway thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisCuster The fact that you are saying is not used for proof that $\sigma$ is an automorphism. Actually, we have to use the fact in order to show that $\sigma$ is a bijection, which does not matter with my question. I just didn't omit the fact by mistake. I'm sorry to confuse.

Comment: That's what I figured.  I wondered why you brought it up again.  You did use it earlier though.  Ok.  Good to know.  This is actually an interesting result.  The result I had known had been for $G$ cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine. So is your use of the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian.

You could be more specific about which corollary to Lagrange's  Theorem you're using, although I think it's implicit.

Comment: If you don't mind, what does Lagrange's theorem have to do with it?

Comment: Paraphrasing the OP: the observation that $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$. It's not quite Lagrange's Theorem, but it follows from it, @ChrisCuster.

Comment: In fact, I used the Lagrange's Theorem to prove bijection. So there is no relationship between the Theorem and proof of isomorphism.

Comment: In addition, the Corollay is that if |g|=n then $g^n=1$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: @Chris Custer Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  And thank you.  But, it may be just me again, but how does the fact that for any $g\in G$ we have $g^n=e$ help us prove $\sigma$ is an automorphism?